# How to render twitter feeds in Angular Application?

Tags: angular

In my project, twitter feeds not rendering, I have tried debugging still not able to find, so I need help.

I have also tried some other stackoverflow answers, which was not working for me.

here is my code,

**index.html**

```
<script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

**app.component.html**

```
<a class="twitter-timeline" data-width="467" data-height="500" [href]="twitterurl">Tweets by {{ twitterurl }}</a>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
twitterurl: SafeResourceUrl = '';

constructor(public sanitizer: DomSanitizer){}

ngOnInit(){
let twitterurl = //will come from server
this.twitterurl = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(twitterurl);
}
```

Thanks

Comment: How you are calling twitter API to get the feeds?

Comment: In html file I have used the anchor tag, got from publish.twitter.com